# Fancyhdr footer moved to one side

Tags: header-footer, positioning

I have a problem with foter position. I am using fancyhdr and I only want the number on the footer, in the center. I'm using:

```
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
```

But in normal pages, the number it's moved to one side, and I don't know why. I know it should be centered with the text (not the page), but it isn't where it should be.

This code reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,fleqn,twoside,openright,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

%%%% PACKAGES %%%%
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[catalan]{babel}
\usepackage[catalan]{varioref}                                          

\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%%%% CUSTOM SETTINGS %%%%

% ¤¤ MARGINS ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\checkandfixthelayout                                   

% ¤¤ CHAPTER APPEARANCE ¤¤ %
\usepackage{color,calc,graphicx,soul,fourier}
\definecolor{niceblue}{RGB}{49,79,79}
\makeatletter
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth}
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}}
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter}
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{%
\resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
\colorbox{niceblue}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}%
}}%
\rotatebox{90}{%
\resizebox{%
\heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}%
{!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
\raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
}
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}}
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedright ##1\par}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{-100pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{2.5cm}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-1cm}
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\color{niceblue}}
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par}
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{daleif1}                                              

\pagestyle{plain}                                                                                           

\begin{document}                                                                                                    

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% HEADERS %%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textit{ \nouppercase{Autor}} }
\fancyhead[LO]{\textit{ \nouppercase{\leftmark}} }
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
  \fancyhf{} % remove everything
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

%%%% Content %%%%
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{text.tex}

\end{document}
```

There must be something not compatible with fancyhdr, but I don't know where to find it...

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please, strip down your files to a single, minimal document illustrating the problem and add the code as an edit to your question.

Comment: While this question may seem complete in terms of providing all the necessary details, the provided code is very large and incomplete. Moreover, it is posted on a link that may be dead once the problem is solved. You should consider your question from the community's perspective, and whittle it down to what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina and Werner, I have edited the question. I have reduced the code to less than a 100 lines, so I think now it's more clear. The problem is that I copied the layout from another university, which had a lot of packages and configuration, and now I'm having problems in adapting it for my university... Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help friends! I found the problem...

fancyhdr should be called after the margin settings:

```
%%%% CUSTOM SETTINGS %%%%

% ¤¤ MARGINS ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\checkandfixthelayout 

\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

Now everything is working like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `fancyhdr` seems to be using the page geometry settings which are "in force" when it is loaded to determine the page center.

There are two possibilities:

1. (As noted in XtracT's answer to his own qustion): load `fancyhdr` after changing page geometry.
2. (Better, in my view) since `memoir` provides its own `fancyhdr` type of way of setting headers and footers, use that.

An example of that follows. Incidentally, I have edited the MWE to remove a very large amount of irrelevant material. This is actually part of the necessary process of solving the problem: what can be removed without affecting it is obviously irrelevant, and one pretty quickly tracks it down.

```
\documentclass{memoir}                                               
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} Not needed with Memoir

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{2cm}{*}  
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}  
\checkandfixthelayout

%The problem is with the following code
% \fancypagestyle{plain}{ %
%  \fancyhf{} % remove everything
%  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
%  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
% }

\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{\thepage}{}

\pagestyle{plain}  

\begin{document}                                                                                                    
\lipsum

\end{document}
```